# EndDialog vs DestroyWindow

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui, windows-messages

HI I am create a mimic of the Windows Context menu.

Show dialog does the follow:

1. creates a dialog using `CreateDialogIndirectParam`
2. runs a message loop:

   ```
   while ( ContinueModal() && GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) )
   {
       TranslateMessage( &msg );
       DispatchMessage( &msg );
   }
   ```
3. I the dialog I look for lost focus event of the new window there I set the `ContinueModel` flag to false and call `EndDialog` / `DestroyWindow`.

   - Calling `EndDialog` doesn't kill my dialog, `DestroyWindow` does. Is this ok, can anyone explain why?

Thanks!
D.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like it says in the first line of the documentation, [`EndDialog` ends modal dialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your dialog is not modal, so `EndDialog` is the wrong function. [The documentation for `CreateDialogIndirectParam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says

> To destroy the dialog box, use the DestroyWindow function.

Comment: I actually figured that much after digging some more in the doucment.
But you are right, thanks for that!! I had lots of fun playing around with Spy++ :)

Comment: 2021 Update: It appears `EndDialog` also closes modeless dialogs now (at least it consistently does so on my system). That's kind of cool because it sometimes allows using the same `DLGPROC` regardless of whether the dialog is displayed modally or not. But in practice you can't really use it because *it's not documented*. Which is doubly bad because you can't rely on an undocumented "feature", but at the same time, bugs go unnoticed because it *happens to work*.

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior your describe. EndDialog still does not destroy the dialog.

Comment: @RaymondChen Upon further investigation, you are entirely correct (tested in a new "Windows Desktop Application" template project in Visual Studio, replacing the `DialogBox` call (to the "About" box) with `CreateDialog` + `ShowWindow`). It does not *destroy* the dialog, but it effectively hides it. Not with `ShowWindow` though, as I'm not seeing a `WM_SHOWWINDOW` message in Spy++. In fact, I don't know exactly what it does, but it removes `WS_VISIBLE`. Regardless, it's a difficult-to-find bug because at first glance it looks like it does the right thing.

Comment: @RaymondChen If the dialog created with `CreateDialogIndirectParam` is modal, then it should be destroyed with `EndDialog`, otherwise if it's not modal then with  `DestroyWindow` is my conclusion correct?

Comment: @metablaster the documentation is correct. Use DestroyWindow to destroy a dialog that was created with CreateDialogIndirectParam. EndDialog is for destroying modal dialogs (telling the internal dialog message loop to exit). For CreateDialogIndirectParam, there is no internal dialog message loop.